# Java timer not triggering after a random time

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a Java Swing timer which updates a label every second. After starting the timer, the label is updated every second and everything works well.

Then after a random time interval, which changes from execution to execution, the label stops being updated. I've put a breakpoint in the timer update code and it no longer gets triggered.

I've also put log statements in all the places where I would normally stop the timer, but none of those places are called.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: Here is the sample of the code

```
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent arg0) {
            secondsRemaining--;
            System.out.println("Seconds remaining:" + secondsRemaining);

            //update the progressbar
            double initialLength = currentSettings.getLength()*60;
            double progress = (initialLength - secondsRemaining)/initialLength ;
            progressBarTime.setProgress(progress);

            //update the progress label
            progressPercentage.setText(((int)(progress * 100))  + "%");

            if (secondsRemaining >= 0) {
                updateTimeRemaining(secondsToString(secondsRemaining));
            } else {
                System.out.println(">0 seconds TIMER STOPPED with the number of seconds = " + secondsRemaining);
                treatmentTimer.stop();

                // set the status to Finished
                currentState = State.FINISHED;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the timer initialization:

```
tTimer = new Timer(1000, actionListener);
tTimer.start();
```

What's strange is that the program works fine on a PC with JRE 7u7 installed, i.e. the timer updates the label successfully, but I've tried on two PCs with 7u10 and this timer stopping issue happens on both.

Comment: any exceptions thrown anywhere? (log files, system out/err etc)? its possible the timer thread was killed by an uncaught exception

Comment: Please show us your code, we are not wizards. [A SSCCE would be great](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I solved the problem. The garbage collector was removing the timer instance, for some unknown reason. I put a

```
System.out.println("message");
```

Inside the actionlistener of the timer, so that it would not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

Exception might be thrown, use try catch or Use UncaughtExceptionHandler to trace.